# Reducer doesn't update state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, reducers

I am trying to create a reducer to update a property in object, but i cant be able to update and store the new state information

**Reducer**

```
  export default function hideCardNumber(state = INITIAL_STATE, action: Action) { 
  if (action.type === 'HIDE_CARDNUMBER') {
  return { 
      ...state,
      data: {...state.data, action }}
  }
  else 
    return state
}
```

**Action**

```
export const toggleViewNumberCard = (cardId: number, hideCardNumber: boolean) => {
  return {
    type: 'HIDE_CARDNUMBER',
    cardId,
    hideCardNumber,
  }
}
```

**dispatch to action**

```
 function handleToggleViewCardNumber() {
    cards.map((card: Card) => {    
      if (card.cardId === props.activeCard ) {
        dispatch(toggleViewNumberCard(
          card.cardId,
          !card.hideCardNumber,
        ))
      }
    })
  }
```

**Initial State**

```
export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  activeCard: 0,
  data: [
    {
      cardId: 0,
      cardName: 'Card',
      cardUsername: 'Name',
      cardNumber: '1234 1234 1234 1234',
      hideCardNumber: false, <-- Trying to replace this property when reducer update
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update reducer like this:

```
const {hideCardNumber, cardId} = action;
return { 
    ...state,
    data: state.data.map(item => item.cardId === cardId ? {...item, hideCardNumber} : item )
}
```

Comment: It still continue to not create new state, i have logged and it return the first state unmodifiable

Comment: You wrong in when the dispatch action. Please show more about `props.activeCard` and the way you call `handleToggleViewCardNumber`

Answer (score 0):

In real-world scenarios, cardID will be a hash. Also to easily maintain the store data when the application grows *INITIAL_STATE* should be like this.

```js
 export const INITIAL_STATE = {
    activeCard: 0,
    data: {
        123456: {
            cardId: 123456,
            cardName: 'Card',
            cardUsername: 'Name',
            cardNumber: '1234 1234 1234 1234',
            hideCardNumber: false, 
      },
    }
  }
```

Then the *Reducer* will be like this.

```js
export default function hideCardNumber(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    if (action.type === 'HIDE_CARDNUMBER') {
        return {
            ...state,
            data: {
                ...state.data,
                [action.cardId]: {
                    ...state.data[action.cardId],
                    hideCardNumber: action.hideCardNumber
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        return state
}
```

If the *activeCard* matches one of the IDs in the *cards*, the code will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

first of all it's  better to put you data in payload like:

```
export const toggleViewNumberCard = (cardId: number, hideCardNumber: boolean) => {
 return {
  type: 'HIDE_CARDNUMBER',
  payload : {
    cardId,
    hideCardNumber,
  }
```

}
}

looks like you have array of cards ,first of all you must have find your current card that you wanna replace using cardid like this:

```
  const index = state.data.findIndex(
    (card) => cardId === action.payload.cardId
  );
```

then copy your old array :

```
      const newArray = [...state.data];
```

then replace that index of newarray with your new hideCardNumber value like this:

```
  newArray[index] = {
    ...newArray[index],
    action.payload.hideCardNumber
  };
  return {
    ...state,
    data: newArray,
  };
```

i hope it would help you